# How to restrict user input of 24 format time into input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, input, mask

I have an input field with time in HH:MM. And I need to manage that users can only enter correct time, to prevent them from entering wrong time.

A time in 24-Hour Format Regular Expression Pattern is

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]
```

And I've found mask input plugin https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

But I dont know how to do what I want.
Thx a lot.

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Question needs to show more research effort. What is wrong with the plugin you posted?

Comment: Everything is fine with plugin, but I didn't understand – how to do what I want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/YFMev/) ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#time").inputmask("h:s",{ "placeholder": "hh/mm" });
});​
```

Comment: Yes! But how did u find that?

Comment: I read the source, seriously ! I took a look inside the source of the date extension in the jQuery.inputmask plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. From now I'll try to do it by myself. Cheers! :)

Comment: how about adding AM and PM?

Comment: @Code Demon the original question was for 24 hour format

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the plugin you referenced since I don't see a demo page for it. I find that if you need the user to enter times or dates in a certain way, you can't let them key anything. So we use calendar date pickers for dates, and this is the best time picker I've found: http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).inputmask("h:s",{ autoUnmask:true });
```

Answer (score -1):

also can use this code

```
var selector = document.getElementById("aaa");
Inputmask("(09|19|20|21|22|23):(09|19|29|39|49|59)").mask(selector);
```

Comment: this is not a valid time regex